# Printing raw field value to use in path to files

Tags: nodes, theming, entities

I have field called "field_cat_id" which has a numerical value (10201; 10202 etc). The field represents a category id and it is also used to arrange PDF files,

I would like to print this (raw) value and use it in the path as shown below in the snippet of my node.tpl.php:

```
    <?php
     $catid = print $content['field_cat_id'][0]['#markup'];
       $path = "/home/site/library/files/" . $catid . "/";// to switch to this once all is working
    $files = scandir($path); ?>

    <ul id="booklist">
      <?php foreach ($files as &$value) {
        echo "<li> <a href='http://localhost/library/files/".$catid."/".$value."' >".$value."</a></li>";
    }?>
    </ul>
```

The output for $path comes out like this:

```
/home/site/library/files/1/
```

Where am i going wrong? When I run

```
   <?php print $content['field_cat_id'][0]['#markup']; ?>
```

The output is for example "10201"

Answer (score 1):

```
$catid = print $content['field_cat_id'][0]['#markup'];
```

Try removing the print.

Comment: Amazing. It worked! Thank you. I don't have enough credits to vote you up otherwise i would have. Once again thank you.